# PHP Copy function with update

Tags: php, xml

I am using php copy() function to copy a php doc into a xml doc and it works fine:

```
echo copy("copy.php","destination.xml");
```

But i need to update the destination xml doc with an extra line

```
<title>test</title>
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `copy` function here:

```
$data = '<title>test</title>' . file_get_contents('copy.php');

file_put_contents('destination.xml', $data);
```